# IE Window Name Being Ignored?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, window

I wrote an HTML page which names its window upon loading via the `onload` method. Then clicking a button on the page opens another window with a form whose search results should go back and be displayed in the original window that was named. This works fine in Firefox. Then the bloody corporation I work for standardized on IE in which the form search results show up in the same window as the form window itself, apparently ignoring the direction to window.open in the existing, original window.

Ideas?

Comment: This is a bit confusing to follow verbally; could you post some code that shows what you've done so far to try and fix the problem?

Comment: add your pieces of code.

Comment: "Ideas?" is a poor request for help. Consider revising your question to include the exact outcome you are looking for and also consider posting a code snippet of the 'trouble spot.' Stack Overflow is about helping you edit your code, we can't do that with code to look at